# Break Nested some or map JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lodash

```js
PC = {a:{ID: "abc",options:{x1:"100", x2:"200"}},b:{ID: "d",options:{x2:"100", x3:"200"}}}


pro = {
  "pro": [
    {
      "pID": "abc",
      "attributes": {
        "xyz": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        ],
        "foo": "フルプレミアム"
      }
    }
  ]
}
functionX() {
        let isND = true;
        if (pro === null || pro === [] || pro.length === 0) {
            return isND;
        } else if (pro.length > 0) {
             some(PC, (p) => {
                 some(p.options, (o, k) => {
                     some(pro, (item) => {
                        if (p.ID === item.pID && k === 'xyz') {
                        if (item.attributes[k] !== []) {
                            isND = false;
                        }
                    } else if (p.ID === item.pID && k !== 'xyz') {
                        if (item.attributes[k] !== '') {
                            isND = false;
                        }
                    }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
        return isND;
    }
```

I have to iterate through 3 different collections to check my condition and return a value. I am trying to exit the nested some or map if one of my if- else conditions satisfy. I tried passing return true after isND = false but doesn't work. Can someone help resolve this.

Comment: Have you thought of using the 'break' key word?

Comment: What is `some()`? `PC` doesn't appear to be a valid JS array either. Please share your actual code and data structures

Comment: i have corrected the PC. it's an object which holds key value pairs. where values are objects @phil

Comment: Even after your update, `PC` is still not valid. Are your `options` meant to be arrays or objects?

Comment: options are objects

Comment: Again, what is `some()`. Also, what is `condition`? `if (condition) {...} else if (condition) {...}` makes zero sense

Comment: I have updated the condition and the json. There is absolutely no issue with the conditions, except for the fact that i can't exit the loop

Comment: It is lodash some

Comment: Your example is still missing data. Where does the `ID` property come from? Your `PC` object values only have an `options` property

Comment: FYI, you cannot compare arrays using `===`. It will always return `false` unless they are actually the same reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will exit early if any of the callbacks return `true` so you could `return` the result that way.

It's not very clear but it seems you want to use this *"early exit"* feature while returning the inverse. How about something like this...

```js
// ignoring "if (pro === null || pro === [] || pro.length === 0)" for this example

// return the inverse
return !Object.values(PC).some(({ ID, options }) => {
  return Object.entries(options).some(([k, o]) => {
    // here "k" is one of your "x1", "x2", etc keys
    // and "o" is the corresponding value

    return pro.pro.some(item => {
      // return "true" if any of your "conditions" are met
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Object.values(PC).some(({ ID, options }) => {
                return Object.entries(options).some(([k]) => {
                    return (pro.pro).some((item) => {
                        if (condition) {
                            if (condition) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            return true;
                        } else if (condition) {
                            if (condition) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                        return null;
                    });
                });
            });
```

// Haven't returned the inverse of outer function